# Monitoring the root activity using terraform code and lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudtrail

I have my terraform code that is creating the resources: Event Bridge to trigger the root activity and to send to lambda, lambda to send notification via email. So when I'm testing my lambda function and simulate the root activity is sending notification all good, but when I do actually a sign in to my root account is not working.
I used this aws documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/monitor-iam-root-user-activity.html page. And I have my spoke and hub account connected. But looks like something is not properly set up, so if you can guide me what I`m missing?

Under CloudTrail I can see the consol login, but looks like the Amazon EventBridge is not trigger it , this is my Event pattern:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "userIdentity": {
      "type": ["Root"]
    }
  },
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail", "AWS Console Sign In via CloudTrail"]
}
```

under targets I have my lambda function. But the root activity not going out from cloudtrail event.